# Messaging outside Chrome Extension : between background.js and window just created

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a problem since few days about communication between my background and a window just created.

1. My background create a new tab;
2. In this new tab i create Element ("script") where i put the file named *window_script*;
3. The file *window_script* have to send a message to my *background*;

My code :

*manifest.json*

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["window_script.js", "background.js"],
```

*background.js*

```
//**Create the new tab**
var results = window.open('','_blank');

//**Insert button inside the new tab**
var button = results.document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute("id","Button_Recalculer");
button.innerHTML = "Calculer";
results.document.body.appendChild(button);

//Insert in this new tab the script named "window_script"
var script = results.document.createElement("script");
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL('window_script.js');
(results.document.head || results.document.documentElement).appendChild(script);

//Listen the message comes from outside the chrome extension
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
if(msg.text === 'From_Web')
{
    console.log("its works");
}
});
```

*window_script.js*

```
var Recalcul = document.getElementById('Button_Recalculer');
Recalcul.addEventListener('click', function() {
console.log("Before msg sended");
var url = "jocipeeapnnenbinklbhajdognaaaaaaaaa";
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(url,{text:'From_Web'});
console.log("Msg sended");
});
```

Inside the console of the *window_script*, i see the console.log "before msg sended" and the console.log "msg sended". But inside the console of *background*, i do not see the console.log "Its works", like this the message was not received, whereas it's fine sended by the *window_script*; Have you any idea about? I have already read topic concerning cross messaging, tried, but did not find solution

Thank you

Jeremy

Comment: Nobody have an explicite solution?

Answer (score 0):

The background.js seems OK, but there is a problem when you send the message from the chrome extension.

Based on this article : https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging

"Sending a request from the extension to a content script looks very similar, except that you need to specify which tab to send it to. This example demonstrates sending a message to the content script in the selected tab."

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

I hope this will help,
Phileas